# Redirect a virtualhost http & https to another virtualhost server

Tags: apache, http, redirect, https, virtualhost

I have 2 apache 2.4 serverA and serverB with several virtualhost. All incoming requests arrive on serverA.

How do I forward http and https request for a specific virtualhost name from serverA to serverB?

My wamp ServerA setup is:
into my hosts file
127.0.0.7   example.com

The virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName        example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass         "/" "http://192.168.1.105/"
    ProxyPassReverse  "/" "http://192.168.1.105/"
</VirtualHost>
```

My serverB ip is 192.168.1.105 and I setup a virtual host on it with the same name example.com

when I use `http://example.com` I stay on the wamp home page like `http://localhost`
and when I use `https://example.com` I have error 403 (Forbidden) on serverA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long night, I find a solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass         "/" "http://192.168.1.105/"
    ProxyPassReverse  "/" "http://192.168.1.105/"
    ServerName        example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    "${APACHE_DIR}/conf/ssl_example.com/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${APACHE_DIR}/conf/ssl_example.com/server.key"
    ErrorLog  "logs/example.com-ssl_error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.com-ssl_access.log" common
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass         "/" "https://192.168.1.105/"
    ProxyPassReverse  "/" "https://192.168.1.105/"
    ServerName        example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

in ServerA virtualhost add a simple:

```
Redirect / https://serverb.examample.com/
```

Comment: if this does not work, you either are not adding this in the correct virtualhost, or you are not reaching this virtualhost, or.. there is something else interfering with it, like some other redirect or override.